# SQL selecting where all distinct values exist in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table in which the first two rows are Company, Year. Each company will have some years, but not necessarily all of them:

```
ABC | 2010
ABC | 2011
ABC | 2012
BBC | 2011 //does not have all the years, don't want to select it
```

I'd like to select a list of companies which have ALL the years (not just some of them), but I'm having trouble writing a select query to do that. I imagine this is really easy but I can't figure it out for some reason.

Comment: What does it mean "ALL the years (not just some of them)"? How far back can the dates go? I assume the number of distinct years is not static.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
select company
from your_table
group by company
having count(distinct year) = (select count(distinct year) from your_table)
```

Comment: works perfectly. never knew how useful the 'having' clause is. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
Select * FROM Company Where CompanyId In(
      select CompanyId From Company
      group by CompanyId
      having count(*) = (select count(distinct Year) from Company)
)
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c2f81/11

Note that if you alread know how many years there should be, then obviously you would just say that number instead of doing a select distinct year.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Company
FROM Table
GROUP BY Company
HAVING COUNT(Distinct YEAR) = 3
```